# How to disable an item from a dropdownlist when another item in the dropdownlist is removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Normally I use this line of code to disable an item. And this works fine:

```
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("item1").Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```

However, if I want to remove an different item in the same list, the previous item won't be disabled anymore:

```
dropdownlist1.Items.Remove(dropdownlist1.Items.FindByText("item2"));
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("item1").Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("item1").Attributes.Add("title", "No Access");
```

In comparison, The title/tooltip still works correctly on the line it's supposed to disable, so I don't know why the item won't disable instead.
The position of the `Remove()` function does not matter, and it will prevent disabling regardless if it's before or after adding the "disabled" attribute.

Comment: Why not set the enabled prop of ListItem to false? You can also hide a list item by setting its visible property to false. Then it will not be rendered into the HTML. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled?view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: I've tried the Enabled property before, but it gave the same result. ListItem also doesn't have a Visible property

Comment: I hadn't really looked that much. I assumed it inherited it from Control.

Answer (score 0):

It was a weird and inconsistent issue, but at least I've fixed it now with `Attributes.CssStyle.Add.("display", "none")` instead of using `Remove()`:

```
dropdownlist1.Items.FindByValue("item2").Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
```